# Align columns on single row CSS to create labels for a toggle

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I created a toggle switch (just a fancy CSS input checkbox type) taken from w3schools. This toggle checkbox will switch between two states : Draw and Erase.

I am trying to add some "label" to my checkbox using the the W3.CSS Responsive classes, w3-.row. HTML Code:

`<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav text-center" id="left_col">
                <div class="well ">
                    <div class="w3-row w3-container">
                        <div class="w3-col s4 w3-center" style="width:none">
                            <p>Draw</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-col s4  w3-center" style="width:none">
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="editor_draw_erase"></input>
                                <div class="slider round"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-col s4 w3-center" style="width:none">
                            <p> Erase </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>`

How it looks (The fiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/gdbcn02g/

How I wish it would like:
[toggle switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH9Yl.png)

Maybe w3-row/col is not the best approach to label my toggle switch as I am very new to CSS and everything web-programming. I tried also styling using the .table but same results. Looking forward to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a multitude of options to align things horizontally. The easiest would be to add `display: inline-block;` to your `w3-col` class. You could also add `float: left` or play around with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: display: inline-block is the solution that worked for me. The columns still need a bit of center alignment for the content, to be displayed on the same level with the switch.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}
.w3-col{
  display:inline-block;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav text-center" id="left_col">
                <div class="well ">
                    <div class="w3-row w3-container">
                        <div class="w3-col s4 w3-center" style="width:none">
                            <p>Erase</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-col s4  w3-center" style="width:none">
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="editor_draw_erase" />
                                <div class="slider round"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-col s4 w3-center" style="width:none">
                            <p> Draw </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```